# what the mean of this python command "python main.py -dataset femnist -model cnn"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
python main.py -dataset femnist -model cnn
```

What is the purpose of this command?

This is the command for Python compilation. I don't know the purpose of `-dataset`.

Comment: This isn't a well-known command, so I doubt that it's possible to tell what it's doing or what `-dataset` means. Essentially, `main.py` is a Python script that parses its arguments and acts accordingly. However, what exactly these arguments mean can only be understood by reading `main.py`

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside the of main.py, you should find some code that handles the command line arguments and options, likely using the sys and getopt libraries. It is here that you can find out what it means exactly. Please check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) for more information.

As a guess, it probably just means what dataset you'd like to pass to the model, in this case the femnist dataset, which could mean the mnist dataset, but I can't be sure without looking at main.py. Please post the main.py and I can help more

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).